# Submit form via image

Tags: html, firefox

Is there any way that user submits the form using image instead of the form button while the request made is still the POST rather than GET? It seems that submitting form via image will result into the GET request. I do not want to post it in this manner as I will be posting the account credentials . For instance, I want to log in. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You need:

```
<input type="image" name="blah" ... >
```

Clicking that will submit the form. You'll get extra fileds of blah_x and blah_y to indicate the coordinates the user actually clicked.

More [here](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TYPE_IMAGE.html).

Comment: Note on the POST names. Don't rely on them and the regular input image name. Since they can differ in IE and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have:

```
 <form method=POST>
```

The type of submit should be post for the form.